# Is not valid use "window.addEventListener('load', function(){});" on my Web extension script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-quantum

My web extension was working pretty fine a month ago, but now this is not working anymore.

**What usually do my addon?**
I am injecting a bar on every web page that the user is opening.

**What is doing right now?**
Nothing; I can install my extension but I don't see my bar on the web pages.

I was not sure if I made an update and broke something so, I am using my first extension version (It was tested and worked fine on the pass) but now this first version does not work too.

I think there are some updates on the browser and something is breaking my extension.

**Firefox ESR Version: 52.5.3 (64-bit)**

**Manifest.json**

```
{

"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "MSC Social Bar",
"version": "1.0",

"description": "MSC Social bar can show you the last news",

"icons": {
    "48": "icon/msc.ico",
    "98": "icon/msc-x2.ico"
},

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["./js/vue.js", "./js/msc-scripts.js"],
        "css": ["./css/msc-styles.css", "./css/fonts/msc-icons.css", "./css/fonts/msc-fonts.css"]
    }
],

"applications": {
    "gecko": {
    "id": "borderify@example.com"
    }
}

}
```

**msc-script.js**

```
(function(){

'use strict';

   window.addEventListener('load', function(){


       if (window.top === window.self) {

           // My code
           ........... 

       }


   });

}());
```

Y have made some test and if I remove this line it works nice:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){});
```

For me is really necessary keep my main skeleton like be.

Could you please help me? There are new updates with this version browser?

I have tested it on this version **Firefox Quantum 57.0.1** and it works fine.

Comment: You don't need to add a listener. The script will be run automatically when the page loads. Just put the code directly into the IIFE, instead of a listener.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar I will and if something is wrong I hope you can help me again. You are very kind.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @Barmar you are right is not necessary use this

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){});
```